# What exactly is meant by potential of a plate?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, work, potential-energy, capacitance

while going through capacitors, what exactly does the term potential of a plate mean?
does potential of a plate mean potential "at any point" on the plate, i.e the work done in bringing a unit positive test charge from infinity to that point?

Comment: Be careful: there are two ways to talk of the potential of a plate.  Formally, yes, it's derived by setting $V(\infty)=0$, but more often when people talk about the potential of a plate they mean the _difference_ in electric potential between the two plates.  That difference relates to the energy to move a charge from one plate to another (and thus to the energy stored by the fields).

Answer (score 1):

Since the plates of a standard capacitor are conductive, they will have the same potential over their entire surface. So yes, the potential is referenced to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Electric potential at a point is defined as work done in bringing a unit positive charge from infinity to that point keeping electrostatic constant.

Comment: This doesn't make a reference to doubt about whether we consider any point on the plate or something else.